# Probability of a Component Lasting More than 6 Months

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A factory has two spares of a critical system component that has an average lifetime of $1$ month. Find the probability that the three components (the operating one and the two spares) will last more than 6 months. Assume the component lifetimes are exponential random variables.

Letting $X$ as the total lifetime of the three device:
$$
P[X>6]=1-P[X≤6]
$$
Using the 3-Erlang Distribution
$$
P[X>6]=1-\sum^2_{k=0}{6^k\over k!}e^{-6}≈0.93803
$$

However, the book discarded $1$ so that $P[X>6]≈0.06197$ which is a contradiction to the formula introduced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanity check: the three components combined last 3 months on average, so it is unlikely for them to last more than 6 months. So the book's answer is likely correct.

The formula you are using is the expression for $P(X \le 6)$. (For instance, see the expression for the CDF of the [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution).)

Alternatively, if you are using the Poisson process interpretation, you can interpret the event $X > 6$ equivalently as "there are zero, one, or two component failures within the first 6 months," so the probability is $P(N=0) + P(N=1) + P(N=2)$ where $N \sim \text{Poisson}(6)$.

Comment: It looks like I have jumbled the Poisson distribution with derivation of the m-Erlang distribution.

Comment: @mkcpz Updated my answer with a Poisson distribution interpetation.